# Removing end of cell/row from word file

Tags: ms-word

[Image with end of cell/row mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWAXz.png)

I want to remove the extra page which I believe is present because of this end of cell/row mark, which I am unable to delete after many tries. I believe this is because of this mark.

I tried deleting the extra page from navigation pane and many other options but none of them worked.

Comment: This line is there because the previous table does not fit in the previous page by little. I would try the following. Expand the page's bottom or top margin by little. Or make some spaces between paragraphs smaller.